# C++ disassembler?

Tags: g++, decompiling, decompiler

Let me just say that I am now backing up everything.

I accidentally typed this line, `g++ -o source.cc source.cc`

And I now have a binary instead of my source. Does anyone know of a good dissembler for C++ in the command line... I have all the function prototypes and structure definitions if that is of any help.

Comment: We've all been there and learned that lesson! Time to start keeping your source under [source control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/78845) and perhaps start using [make](http://stackoverflow.com/q/73799/78845) to take care of those pesky `g++` command-lines. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, source control Looks very helpful!

Comment: I figured this was different since it was my own code and I had structure definitions/previous versions

Comment: If you still have it in your editor use the undo commands to revert to previous buffers.  Though I'm guessing you don't have the buffers opened...?

Comment: Nope... I just use vim with no buffers.